# How to convert use transform css property into tailwind css?

Tags: html, css, sass, tailwind-css

I am trying to convert this class into css some of the things are straightforward to convert.

But this 3 props I am not sure is possible to have it tailwind.css?

```
.toast-top-center {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99;
  top: 10%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

Trying to add with tailwind CSS

.toast-top-center {
  @apply fixed z-40;

  top: 10%; 
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
``
```

Comment: I think the ```transform``` prop is not possible. But the ```Left: 50%;``` = ```left-1/2```.
And for the ```Top: 10%;```  you can use [this](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/top-right-bottom-left#customizing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS class with Tailwind would be:

```
.toast-top-center {
  @apply fixed z-99 transform -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 left-1/2 top-1/10;
}
```

For this to work you would either have to switch from Tailwind to [WindiCSS](https://windicss.org/), or change your tailwind.config.js like this:

```
module.exports = {
    theme: {
      inset: {
       // Other fractions if you need them elsewhere
       '1/2': 50%,
       '1/10': '10%',
      },
      zIndex: {
        // Other indexes if you need them elsewhere
        '99': 99
      }
    }
  }
```